# How to get PDF from http request/response stream

Tags: c#, http, pdf, request, response

I have a url like this "https://site.com/cgi-bin/somescript.pl?file=12345.pdf&type=application/pdf". When i go to this url it will dispaly an pdf in my browser in an iframe. Is it possible to save this pdf? I am thinking of getting the http response stream and dump it into a file. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
             const string FILE_PATH = "C:\\foo.pdf";
             const string DOWNLOADER_URI =  "https://site.com/cgi-bin/somescript.pl?file=12345.pdf&type=application/pdf";

            using (var writeStream = File.OpenWrite(FILE_PATH)) 
            {
                var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(DOWNLOADER_URI) as HttpWebRequest;
                var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
                httpResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(writeStream);
                writeStream.Close();
            }
```